# Accessing struct field by a given string that contains the full path

Tags: go

A validator package gives me back strings like this if a given field in my struct doesn't pass the validation:

```
myString := "Stream.Fields[0].Name"
```

How can i use this string to gain access to the struct field specified in it? I need to reference it somehow but i have no idea where to start with.

I'm beginning to learn Go and already came across the "Reflect" package which seems to be able to do that but i don't know what to look for or how to formulate the right question.

Comment: may be make that string compatible with [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and parse using that?

Comment: you need to use `reflection` package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package for this. 
Here I have written a sample function which given an instance and string key like `Stream.Details.Name` will return the `Name` from the field Details of instance `Stream`

This works for structs without `array` or `map` operators , just the `.` operator . You may extend this to support the `[]` aswell

```
func getValueFromStruct(keyWithDots string, object interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    keySlice := strings.Split(keyWithDots, ".")
    v := reflect.ValueOf(object)
    // iterate through field names ,ignore the first name as it might be the current instance name
    // you can make it recursive also if want to support types like slice,map etc along with struct
    for _, key := range keySlice[1:] {
        for v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            v = v.Elem()
        }
        // we only accept structs
        if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("only accepts structs; got %T", v)
        }

        v = v.FieldByName(key)
    }
    return v, nil
}
```

Here is golang play link : https://play.golang.org/p/NIRdGONZBhP

Comment: Thank you for a great example, i'll try to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

This library also exists, which might do what you want:
https://github.com/mcuadros/go-lookup

The lib uses the [reflect package](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) under the hood.